# Apache Read Changed PHP File in Several Minutes

Tags: php, apache

I use Apache as my web server and use PHP 5.5.30.
But I've a problem when I change a PHP file, I need to wait for several minutes until Apache reload my new file. 
Is there any configuration I must set on my httpd.conf?

This is my httpd.conf file http://pastebin.com/D0JN7c56

Comment: Normally Apache picks up on changes instantly. Do you edit files over the network or is there some other reason the files are changed slowly?

Comment: No, I don't. I edit my local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

This is happened because opcache configuration on php.ini.
Just set revalidate frequency

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
```

or disabled opcache

```
opcache.enable=0
```